# Meaning of the word Ghāt

Tags: meaning, translation, subcontinental-english

I am a cartographer and am working on a map for a region in northern India.  My map source is quite old (1910-1920).  There are several named places on the map referring to Ghāts.  Many of these named locations are along rivers or were, at one time, along a river [*note that the river is **not** the Ganges*] that has since shifted to another location.  Examples of these names are: Lachhman Ghāt, Bānsdeo Ghāt, Rām Ghāt, etc.

I have researched this word online and have come to the conclusion that the word (*translated from Hindi*) likely means "passage" or "landing".  Here is the Hindi word for ghāt - घाट.  Several sources suggest that the word defines a wide set of stairs that descend to a water source for the purpose of bathing/cleansing or for funereal cremation.

Here's my problem:
Presuming that the geographic feature is still at the same location in modern day, I cannot discern from online imagery (Google Earth) if these features are still present.

Can the geographic term "ghāt" refer to some other type of feature than what is suggested above?  Can "ghāt" refer to a populated place or a locality/neighborhood?  I have read that the term ghāt can be used to refer to a mountain range or hill, but I don't think this definition applies in this situation.

**River of Colour:** ***The India of Raghubir Singh*** (Phaidon Press Limited, 1998) mentions ghāts as thus:
"During the past thirty years Raghubir Singh has made countless personal journeys across the vast Indian subcontinent. He has traveled along the Ganges, toured the ghats and alleys of Benares and explored the cosmopolitan cities of Calcutta and Mumbai."

This example suggests that the term "ghat" refers to the steps down to a river as outlined above.  However, I question whether the usage of the term on my map source may be referring to some other named map feature.  Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Ghat also ghaut  (gôt, gät) (n.)
*A broad flight of steps leading down to the bank of a river in India, used especially by bathers*.
[Hindi ghāt, from Sanskrit ghaṭṭaḥ, probably of Dravidian origin; akin to Telugu kaṭṭu, gaṭṭu, **dam, embankment**.] AHD

Comment: From the etymology section in the *full* OED: *The senses are here placed in the order of their **occurrence in English**. The **order of development, however, is as follows:** 1. A path of descent to a river; hence a landing-stage, a quay, the place of a ferry. 2. A path down from a mountain; a mountain pass. 3. In plural, the name erroneously given by Europeans to the mountain ranges parallel to the east and west coasts of India.*

Comment: Please present some evidence that the word has been used as an English word, or else this question is off topic.

Comment: @curiousdannii: There's no point in me *linking* to OED - it's subscription-only, so most people here wouldn't be able to follow it. But OED has no less than 4 separate subdefinitions for the word, so I think you must accept that today it's "English".

Comment: @fumblefingers The evidence needs to be edited into the question. And if it's so simply answered by checking a dictionary, then it should be closed for general reference.

Comment: In this circumstance, the term ghāt is a romanized version of a Hindi word.  Romanization is an attempt to latinize a foreign word so that it can be pronounced in a different language - in this case English.  Also, since the map is a British map, I thought it appropriate to post this question in an English forum.  My apologies if there is another forum that is more appropriate for this question.

Comment: @curiousdannii: The specific etymological note I copied from OED might be rather difficult to find elsewhere, so I'd hardly call it GR. And so far as OED are concerned, the *specific geographical location* (***the Ghauts:*** the name applied by Europeans to two chains of mountains along the eastern and western sides of southern Hindostan, known as the Eastern and Western Ghauts) was the first "English" usage. It's a highly specialised question, but I don't see any grounds for finding fault.

Comment: @Fumblefingers Just because a toponym is found on an English map doesn't make it an English word. Is leste from Timor Leste an English word? I don't think so. So quotes saying things like "The ghats of north eastern India are..." are needed to show that it is actually used as a word and not just a name in English.

Comment: @curiousdannii: OED lists the proper noun first, and arguably it wouldn't normally appear in a dictionary (as opposed to an encyclopedia) if that were the *only* usage. But the other three (1: *A mountain pass or defile*, 2: *A passage or flight of steps leading to the river-side*, 3: *A level spot at the top of a river ghat on which Hindus burn their dead; a funeral pyre*) are all effectively just "words". And if you don't see inclusion in OED as evidence that it's a "word" *in English*, I guess we'll just have to agree to disagree.

Comment: @Fumblefingers I already accepted that it's used as a word in English. *But that evidence still needs to be put into the question itself!* Comments are temporary and the question needs to stand alone. And I would prefer the evidence be quotes of the word used in context in sentences, which the OED does provide. I'm not saying that either the OP or you have you have to edit it, but someone needs to!

Comment: @curiousdannii: As it stands, I doubt the mods would delete my first comment. But if it bothers you, by all means edit it into the question text, link or no link.

Comment: For clarification purposes: I added a reference to my original question that uses the word ghāt in an English sentence.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Hindi, not English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider:

> **ghat**
>
> noun
>
> \ˈgȯt, ˈgät\ also ghaut \ˈgȯt, ˈgät\
>
> plural -s
>
> 1
>   *India* **a :  mountain range b :  a mountain pass**
>
> 2
>   *India* **a :**  **a landing place or platform on the bank of a river b :  a passage or flight of steps leading from a landing place or platform to
>   the water's edge** (as for the convenience of bathers) — compare
>   *burning ghat*
>
> Origin of GHAT
>
> Hindi ghāṭ, from Sanskrit ghaṭṭa
>
> First Known Use: 1698 (sense 1)
>
> Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dictionary

Further

> The numerous significant ghats along the Ganges are known generally as
>   the 'Varanasi ghats' and the 'ghats of the Ganges'. In Madhya Pradesh
>   in western India there are further significant ghats along the Narmada
>   River. **People who live on the steps are also called ghats**.
>
> The word is also used in some places outside of the Indian
>   subcontinent where there are Indian communities. For example, in
>   George Town, Penang in Malaysia, the label "Ghaut" is used to identify
>   the **extensions of those streets which formerly ended in ghats** before
>   reclamation of the quayside (e.g., Church St Ghaut - in Malay Gat
>   Lebuh Gereja - is the name of the extension of Church St beyond where
>   the street used to descend to the water via a ghat). In both Penang
>   and Singapore, there are areas named Dhoby Ghaut (dhobi meaning
>   "launderer" or "laundry", depending on whether it refers to a person
>    or a business).
>
> Wikipedia